# Is it possible to broadcast from socket.io-emitter

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

Im currently emitting messages using [socket.io-emitter](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io-emitter) to emit messages (in namespace) from a worker in my app, however now i need to broadcast to all connected sockets(to the namespsace), when something happends, is there any work around there?

For example this is a socket.io exposed(HTTP) emit and broadcast using socket.io adapter to 
be able to run different socket.io instances in different processes

```
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
io.adapter(redis(config.redis));

io.of('/namespace').on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.emit('message', 'Hi you!');
    socket.broadcast.emit('broadcast', 'Heya all!');
});
```

This is now a different process (MQ worker) that is emitting events to the clients

```
var io = require('socket.io-emitter')(redis(config.redis));

var socket = io.of('/namespace');

socket.emit('message', 'Hi you!');            // This works
socket.broadcast('broadcast', 'Heya all!');   // This won't work
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work this way.

With client-emitter you can only emit, then the server process what he want to do with this event.

Server-side :

```
socket.on('msg', function (msg) {

    socket.broadcast.emit('msg', msg);

});
```

client-side :

```
socket.emit('msg', 'msg');
```

Comment: From the docs socket.io-emitter allows you to communicate with socket.io servers easily from non-socket.io processes., im using it to fire messages to the clients from non-socket.io processes like non-socket.io exposed workers

Comment: i edited my answer, you have only emit function, you have to handle the broadcast in server

Comment: @Jujuleder Hi, could you take a look at my post ? i really cant seem to get socket.io-emitter, it's supposed to emit to all servers connected to the same redis pub and sub right ? but i cant log out the errors .. nor do i receive any events from my server https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48146965/i-am-unclear-of-how-to-use-socket-io-emitter-server-to-server